# Redirect home page if another page contain div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, html

I need to do the following:

When access mysite.com check if another page X contain div id "intro", if so, redirect mysite.com  to mysite.com/search. If page x does not contain div id, load mysite.com.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
$('#result').load('Page2.html #intro');
});
</script>
```

page with div id :

```
<div id="intro" style="display: none">My sample content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($)
 if ($('#result').load('page2.html #divID').length === 0){
 window.location.href = "redirect.html";
 }
 </script>
```